# Why VTK invoke cmake/vtkobjectfactory.h.ini

Tags: vtk

I am using VS2017 to compile VTK 8 Example, Cone.cxx, screen as attached. But I do not know how the error show vtkobjectfactory.h.in been invoked?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tICRz.png)

I trace the program and find it initiated by Common/DataModel/vtkPolyData.h
But I can not understand how it worked. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

It can't find some include files. Judging by how your #includes are written, you haven't set path to the vtk include files - you have set correct paths for the few files you are including, but those files are including additional files and they are using relative path - for example, if you open your vtkCamera.h, which you are including, you will find it starts with lines like `#include "vtkRenderingCoreModule.h"`, while in your environment, the "vtkRenderingCoreModule.h" is probably somewhere like `"Rendering/Core/vtkRenderingCoreModule.h"`, so it can't find it. If you wanted to do it this way, you would have to change the paths also in all the files that are being included and that is just not reasonable.

A simple solution is to go to your project properties (right click in the solution explorer on your project name -> properties) -> C/C++ ->General: The first line should be "Additional Include Directories". There, you add a new line with path to the include folder of your vtk installation, probably something like `"C:\program files\VTK 8.0\include\vtk-8.0\"` - if you look in that folder you should find all the vtk's .h files in one place.

Then you can change your code by removing all the folder specifications from the #include paths and simply write `#include vtkConeSource.h` etc. and all files should be found without issues.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Just as I said I am using VS2017 (not CMake), so that I had coded a program to add path for all header files, and header files in *.cxx, that is what I show on my screen. And I just put VTK-8.0.1 in project C++ directory so that project be able to read all related header. When I build it and show the screen which I shown before that is how I can not understand why?